# OpenVPN connection timeout error

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn

It's few months I'm using OpenVPN as well, but now, I get timeout error:

[image]

Any idea what's wrong and how can I fix it?

---

Note that, in the past I've seen this error once and by disable/enabling network drivers (I don't remember which/how exactly) it got working again. This is my network status:

[image]